# error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint32_t

Tags: c++, arduino, char, invalid-characters, uint

I am trying to manually set up a RTC clock.
When doen automatically, this is the working code:

```
clock.setDateTime((__DATE__, __TIME__));
```

But now I want to set it manually and this is what I am trying:

```
char dateTime[20];
strcat(dateTime, "2017,03,22,16,20,04");
//clock.setDateTime((__DATE__, __TIME__));
clock.setDateTime(dateTime);
```

I get the following error(at the last line):

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
```

How to solve?

EDIT:
This is how setDateTime is defined:

```
void setDateTime(uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t hour, uint8_t minute, uint8_t second);
```

Comment: How is `setDateTime` defined?

Comment: @NathanOliver See edit

Comment: Okay.  So you need to split the string into parameters that match how `setDateTime` is defined.

Comment: You're feeding a string (`char *`) to a function that expects integer parameters... that's an invalid conversion (as the compiler is telling you). What do you expect?

Comment: Also, I guess there are multiple declarations for `setDateTime()`, as 1) the one you're showing us shouldn't work with `(__DATE__, __TIME__)` either, and 2) the one you're showing us is not expecting `uint32_t` which is what the compiler complains about.

Comment: Why screw around with strings if you could just call `clock.setDateTime(2017,3,22,16,20,4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDateTime()` accepts `int`s as parameters, yet you give it `char` array.

The call should be:

```
clock.setDataTime(2017, 3, 22, 16, 20, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

`setDateTime()` takes the date as a succession of integers:

```
setDateTime(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

---

Bonus: according to `man strcat`:

> ```
> char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The `strcat()` function appends the *src* string to the *dest* string, ...

Since you use it this way:

```
char dateTime[20];
strcat(dateTime, "2017,03,22,16,20,04");
```

you append `"2017,03,22,16,20,04"` to unitialized memory, which is *undefined behaviour*.